# can not access wp-admin after migrating to openshift

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I recently migrated to Redhat's Openshift PaaS.
My site is little bit slow in loading but working fine but Now I am unable to access wp-admin.

`mysite/wp-admin` is redirecting to `mysite/wp-admin/upgrade.php?_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2F` which says "webpage is not available.

What may be the possible reason behind it and how to resolve the problem?

Comment: Is there any kind of support you could inquire with? Any debug information at all you could think of to add? It's hard to guess based on little info and unfortunately probably not very likely to catch attention of someone on same platform.